# The equivalent of deleted types in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am upgrading Angular to version 13 and this involves updating TypeScrip. I have two problems and I am trying to find information but still without much success.

1. the first problem is with the ClientRect type, it has been removed
   (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029#issuecomment-869224737)
   What can I do to replace it?
2. the second problem is with SVGElementInstance type, it was also removed and I have this condition in my application

   [image]

How can I replace it currently?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: For the first part: I'm pretty sure you want `DOMRect`.